# Is the Ki value always an integer in COMP128v1/2/3 SIMs?

Tags: gsm, sim-card

I'm doing some research about the GSM protocol and how SIM cards work. As far as I've found, the only type of SIMs where the secret value, K<sub>i</sub>, can be extracted are COMP128v1, since it is not really long byte long and can be easily brute-forced knowing the signed response.

I found [more details about the closed 128v2/3 protocol](http://www.hackingprojects.net/2013/04/secrets-of-sim.html), and the author states that the K<sub>i</sub> is actually a 16 byte long number. So, is the K<sub>i</sub> essentially a 16 digits long number?

Comment: When you ask if it's 16 digits long, do you mean **decimal** digits?

Answer (score 0):

Ki is defined in the [ETSI/3GPP spec](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/155200_155299/155205/08.00.00_60/ts_155205v080000p.pdf), Section 3.2 as a 128 bit number.

Each byte contains 8 bits, so your source that said it's 16 bytes long is correct, because 8 x 16 = 128.

In the computer, each bit can contain 1 or zero, so a 128 bit number can contain [binary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number) (base 2) values from 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 to 11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111.

Translated into decimal, that gives a range of values from 0 to (2 to the power 127).

It's sometimes easier to use [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) (base 16), which in this case gives a value range from 0 to 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

Answer (score 0):

Ive almost always seen Ki expressed as a Hexidecimal.

Like this;

```
KI  : AA 33 D0 AB 4A 8B C0 45 3C D0 83 96 9B 79 D3 08
```